# what are some alternative for profiling a R code beside Rprof?

Tags: r, debugging, profiling, profiler

I am new to profiling in `R` after some googling, `Rprof` seems to be a really good package to do that.
but when I try to install it, it gives me the below error:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘Rprof’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)
```

so, is there any as good alternative package exist? or what is the R version which its work on , as there is no information about it in [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/Rprof.html)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Rprof is not a package.  Try `?Rprof`   (There is a package called profr)

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, thanks, which one do you recommend?

Comment: The **aprof** package is nice: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/aprof/index.html

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `lineprof` package, developed by Hadley.

To install type: `devtools::install_github('hadley/lineprof')` (you need the `devtools` package installed: `install.packages('devtools')`.

To use it you need to save your code in a .R file and then source it using `source`.

From documentation:

```
source(find_ex("read-delim.r"))
x2 <- lineprof(read_delim(wine), torture = TRUE)
```

There is more info about the profiler on Hadley's book [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html)

Answer (score 4):

`Rprof` is not a package it's a function.
It should already be installed since it is part of the `utils` package.

You can call it by writing `Rprof()`.